# Change frame_id in messages

Tags: navigation, message, robot-localization, frame-id, messages

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I use kitti_player and robot_localization. kitti_player publich messages with framed_id "/kitti_player" but in  robot_localization I get an error "frame_ids cannot start with a '/' ". How solve this problem?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/242030/change-frame_id-in-messages/) by [vladimir](https://answers.ros.org/users/27791/vladimir/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2016-08-19

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [tomy983](https://answers.ros.org/users/101642/tomy983/) on 2022-06-17**:
Hello,
I also have the same issue but I am unable to change the source code since the topic is coming from an android app (https://aapks.com/apk/ros-android-sensors-driver/). Source code should be fro here: https://github.com/rpng/android_sensors_driver and might even be fixed (imu frame_id is published as "/imu") but I don't have the toolchain to recompile.
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

What if you remove the '/' in your source code? Sometimes ROS will add a '/' for you, so if you give `'/kitti_player'`, things will go wrong. So just give `'kitti_player'` in your code.

---

Originally posted by [Shay](https://answers.ros.org/users/27777/shay/) with karma: 763 on 2016-08-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [vladimir](https://answers.ros.org/users/27791/vladimir/) on 2016-08-22**:
Thanks! I have solved this problem this way